# Filter a List Then Change the Type

Tags: kotlin

How can I cast a list and filter at the same time? I could do this with for loops, but there has to be a Kotlin way that makes it better.

```
fun getList(): List<Animal> = animals

fun test() {
    val list: Dog = getList().filter {
        it.age > 5
    }
}
```

`list` cannot be assigned because `it` is of type `Animal`.

How can I transform the list to `Dog` type and still do the filtering?

Comment: Use `map` to create a new list of `Dog`s.

Comment: How would that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is wrong. According to [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html), filter function returns ***a list*** containing only elements matching the given predicate. So, instead of `val list: Dog` you should use `val list: List<Dog>`.

As far as I understood, you want to get list of dogs from animals list which satisfies `it.age > 5` condition. To fix the issue, you can use `filterIsInstance()`:

```
open class Animal(val age: Int)

class Dog(age: Int) : Animal(age)

fun test() {
    val animals = mutableListOf<Animal>()
    animals.add(Dog(6))
    animals.add(Animal(7))
    animals.add(Dog(8))

    val list: List<Dog> = animals
        .filterIsInstance(Dog::class.java)
        .filter {
            it.age > 5
        }
}
```